# Polymer- paper-spinner change size

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to change the size of paper-spinner.By setting the css height and width properties.
 This change the size of the element but the element corrupted.

Their is a way to change the size that the spinner will be also small or bigger?

Answer (score 7):

Set both the CSS width and height of the container element.

```
paper-spinner {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}
```